# Prove that $f(m,n) = 2^m(2n +1 ) -1 $ is a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Basically this proves that set of natural numbers is equinumerous to its cartesian product with itself.
f
I have tried proving injectivity and surjectivity.Here is what I have done so far.

To prove injectivity I have assumed that $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$ then I proved contradiction when $a=b$ and $c\neq d$,as well as when $a\neq b$ and $c=d$.I have managed to get contradiction for those cases but I did not manage to get a contradiction when both $a\neq b$ and $c\neq d$

For surjectivity I tried using the fact that if some sets(namely range of function and set of natural numbers) are subsets of each other then they are equal.That has led me nowhere

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Note that $f(a,b)=f(c,d)\Leftrightarrow f(a,b)+1=f(c,d)+1$ and try to think less abstract and more specific. Try to think.

Comment: Every positive integer $N$ has a unique representation in the form $N=2^m(2n+1)$, where $m$ and $n$ are non-negative.

Comment: Andre Nicolas,can you provide a proof for that statement?

Comment: The set of non-negative integers $x$ such that $2^x$ is non-empty and bounded above, so there is a largest one. Call it $m$. Then $\frac{N}{2^m}$ is odd, so of the shape $2n+1$. That proves existence. For uniqueness, if $2^a(2b+1)=2^c(2d+1)$, where without loss of generality $a\ge c$, we have $2^{a-c}(2b+1)=2d+1$ so $a-c=0$.

Comment: If the matter were just to prove $| \Bbb N \times \Bbb N| = |\Bbb N|$, then $f(m,n) = 2^m 3^n$ would suffice, no? (;

Answer (score 5):

You may have overcomplicated the proof of injectivity: if we assume $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$, we have that:

$$2^a(2b+1) = 2^c(2d+1)$$
By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (unique factorization), since $2b+1$ and $2d+1$ are odd, we must have $a = c$. This is because the highest power of $2$ dividing both sides must be the same, and $2$ certainly does not divide $2b+1$ and $2d+1$. Hence $a =b$, and it follows that $b = d$, so $f$ is injective.

Surjectivity follows from the Fundamental Theorem as well: if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ we can factorise $x-1$ into primes, and letting $k$ be the product of all of the odd prime factors of $x-1$, have $x -1 = 2^mk $ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $k$ is certainly odd so $k = 2n+1$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $x =2^m(2n+1) + 1 = f(m,n)$, so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Hence $a=c$, and it follows that $b=d$, So $f$ is injective. There is a typo error I think

Answer (score 1):

Often, the easiest way to show that something is a bijection is to find its inverse.

Given $x \in \mathbb N$, by repeatedly dividing by $2$ where possible, we can write $x + 1 = 2^sr$ where $r$ is odd. Then $m = s$ and $n = \frac{1}{2}(r-1)$